# Recursive function in c not working

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int power(int a)
{
    if(a<=0)
        return 1;
    else
        return((int)pow(5.0,a)+power(a--));
}
void main()
{
    printf("%d",power(2));
}
```

The above function was used by me for a bigger program I am working on, but it was not able to execute in C. Kindly point me out the bug.

Comment: Just replace `a--` with `--a` (or, preferably, `a - 1`).

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
return((int)pow(5.0,a)+power (a--));
```

To

```
return((int)pow(5.0,a)+power (a-1));
```

The reason that it didn't work is that `a--` returns the current value of `a` and not the decremented value of `a`. So your recursive function never ends and it is an infinite-recursion.